# STRIPE, collect payment then pay out to IBAN

Tags: next.js, payment-gateway, payment

I have app where user will pay some money, also user will pay platform fee.
I have account in STRIPE, and platform fee will go to STRIPE account.
Full price will go to IBAN account. I am getting error:

StripeInvalidRequestError:
No such destination: 'SK1111111111111111111111'

Can you please tell me why I am getting this error? Is there wrong format of IBAN, or should I use different payment method? Thanks for any help.

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {

  const Price = req.body.Price * 100
  const id = req.body.id

  const fees = (Price * 15) / 100

  const item = await Product.findById(id) // I am getting product, all good

  console.log('item iban', item.iban) //  SK1111111111111111111111


  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        name: item.name,
        amount: Price,
        currency: 'EUR',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],

     payment_intent_data: {
      application_fee_amount: fees,
      transfer_data: {
        destination: item.iban || null
      }
    },  

    success_url: process.env.STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL,
    cancel_url: process.env.STRIPE_CANCEL_URL,
  });

     console.log(session)    
   
}


export default handler
```